# PrimeFaces organigram division issue

Tags: primefaces

In PrimeFaces 6.2 [organigram showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/organigram.xhtml), when I remove employees from Team Mobile division

**Before**

[image: PrimeFaces Organigram - Team Mobile initial]

**After**

[image: PrimeFaces Organigram - Team Mobile no employees]

it shows iOS division as a subdivision of Android.

**Exected**

[image: PrimeFaces Organigram - Team Mobile no employees expected]

I checked the options and I found no solution for this.

Comment: @Kukeltje Can you be more specific, what is missing? I linked to PrimeFaces' showcase, sources are also available. What is unclear?

Comment: Several things. First it is common practice to post code inline in SO since external sites may be volatile. Secondly, there is lots of code in the showcase (including number of nodes, events, context menu etc) that does not play a role in your problem. So it is not a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same problem in a earlier version and just added

> skipLeafHandling="true"

to my nodes, so every node is placed like there could be a leaf.

```
<p:organigramNode  type="division" skipLeafHandling="true" styleClass="division"
                    icon="ui-icon-suitcase" iconPos="left">
                    ....
                </p:organigramNode>
```

Comment: Ouch... I wanted to test that part but forgot. Good addition.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be 'by design' and 'collapsing' childeren on the **same level** and not as a subdivision since there are no lines in between. Try dragging employees to other nodes that already contain employees. It makes them appear identical

[image]

Even combinations of employees and empty teams.

[image]

If you want to prevent this, see the other answer by @VitalijKochno