# Issue in setting values in p:organigram

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi i am facing problem in setting values in **organigram primeFaces**.

I want to show reporting to employees, all things are working perfect but the issue only i am facing is that parent nodes are repeating, according to number of childs.

so please suggest me any best way to handle it.

**Here is Model:**

```
public TreeMap<String, String> getALLEmployees(OrganigramView ob) {

    ConnectionHandler conHandler = ConnectionHandler.getConnectionHandler();
    Connection con = conHandler.getConnection();

    Statement stmt = null;
    ArrayList<OrganigramView> list = new ArrayList();

    OrganigramView obs;
    TreeMap<String, String> tm = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String selectQry = "select emp.* ,emp.Name as reportingName,ejd.`REPORTING_BOSS_ID`,emp2.`NAME` as reportToBy, emp.`EMPLOYEE_ID` as empID\n"
                + "from employee emp \n"
                + "JOIN employee_job_detail ejd ON ejd.`EMPLOYEE_ID` = emp.`EMPLOYEE_ID`\n"
                + "JOIN employee emp2 ON emp2.`EMPLOYEE_ID` = ejd.`REPORTING_BOSS_ID` \n"
                + "  WHERE emp.COMPANY_ID = 4 and emp.`PROFILE_STATUS` = 1 ";


        System.out.println("selectQry : " + selectQry);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectQry);
        while (rs.next()) {
            tm.put( rs.getString("Name"),rs.getString("reportToBy")  );


            System.out.println(tm.size());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conHandler.freeConnection(con);
    }

    return tm;
}
```

**Here is Bean:**

```
protected OrganigramNode addDivision(OrganigramNode parent, String name, String... employees) {
    OrganigramNode divisionNode = new DefaultOrganigramNode("division", name, parent);
    divisionNode.setDroppable(true);
    divisionNode.setDraggable(true);
    divisionNode.setSelectable(true);

    if (employees != null) {
        for (String employee : employees) {
            OrganigramNode employeeNode = new DefaultOrganigramNode("employee", employee, divisionNode);
            employeeNode.setDraggable(true);
            employeeNode.setSelectable(true);
        }
    }

    return divisionNode;
}
```

**Here is XHTML**

```
     <p:organigram id="organigram"
                                  widgetVar="organigram"
                                  value="#{organigramView.rootNode}"
                                  var="node"


                                >

                        <p:ajax event="dragdrop" process="@this" update="@form:growl" listener="#{organigramView.nodeDragDropListener}" />
                        <p:ajax event="select" process="@this" update="@form:growl" listener="#{organigramView.nodeSelectListener}" />
                        <p:ajax event="contextmenu" process="@this" />
                        <p:ajax event="collapse" process="@this" update="@form:growl" listener="#{organigramView.nodeCollapseListener}" />
                        <p:ajax event="expand" process="@this" update="@form:growl" listener="#{organigramView.nodeExpandListener}" />

                        <p:organigramNode>
                            <h:outputText value="#{node.data}" />
                        </p:organigramNode>

                        <p:organigramNode type="root"
                                          style="border-radius: 10px;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{node.data}" />
                        </p:organigramNode>

                        <p:organigramNode type="division"
                                          styleClass="division"
                                          icon="pi pi-briefcase"
                                          iconPos="left">
                            <h:outputText value="#{node.data}" />
                        </p:organigramNode>

                        <p:organigramNode type="employee"
                                          styleClass="employee"
                                          icon="pi pi-user">
                            <h:outputText value="#{node.data}" />
                        </p:organigramNode>
                    </p:organigram>
```

Again i am repeating that all things are working perfect but only parent nodes are repeating, according to number of child nodes, but i want that one parent and there child should be shown.

**EXPECTED[image]:**

**OUT PUT**
[image]

Comment: Sure the additional children are not hidden behind one another? And that this is the result of the number of nodes.

Comment: @Kukeltje could you please give example.

Comment: Of what? You trying with less nodes?

Comment: @Kukeltje  yes please provide example

Comment: How can **_I_** provide an example for **_your_** data? Filter your sql (add a limit 0,5 or whatever)

Comment: Or try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276256/primefaces-organigram-division-issue